# Implications of symmetric probability density function

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Consider a real-valued random variable $X$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ with probability density function $f$. Suppose $f$ is symmetric around zero. This implies that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x)dx=0$. Can we say something about $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x (f(x))^2dx$ ?

Comment: Does this preclude the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution)? It is symmetric about zero, but has undefined mean.

Comment: What do you mean by precluding the Cauchy distribution?

Comment: Are you allowed to consider the Cauchy distribution? Because you claim that symmetry about zero implies expectation zero. But this is not true for the Cauchy distribution

Comment: Thanks for the comment! hence, the correct statement is "if $f$ is symmetric around zero and the first moment exists, then the first moment is zero"

Comment: Sounds better.$ $

Comment: $f$ symmetric around zero means that it is an even function $f(x)=f(-x)$, isn't it? If this is true, isn't your second integral zero as well [the integrand is the product of an even function and an odd function, so it is odd]?

Comment: Thanks, I don't get the even odd argument, could you explain more (in case you have time)?

Comment: OK, I am not sure how familiar you are with the concept of even/odd function, so I assume you aren't and try an explanation from scratch [apologies if my assumption is completely off ;-)]. The integral between $-\infty$ and $\infty$ of an odd function is zero, because an odd function (for which $f(x)=-f(-x)$) has a graph that is symmetric w.r.t. the origin, so positive contributions to the integral for $x>0$ are offset by equal contributions with a negative sign for $x<0$. So, if $f(x)$ is even [as it seems], $(f(x))^2$ is even as well, and $x (f(x))^2$ is odd...does this make more sense?

Comment: ok, I see, thanks a lot for the explanation

Comment: you're welcome.